# Angular2 router - parent route with component that redirects to default children

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a `SecuredModule` that is loaded dynamically (in my `app.routing.ts`) when user visits `/secured` path.

In this module I have the following route definition:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: SecuredComponent, , children: [
        { path: 'application', loadChildren: 'app/application/application.module#ApplicationModule'}
    ]},
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'application' }

];
```

As this module is loaded with `loadChildren`, then the `''`(default) route in the example refers actually to `'/secured'`. In `''` path I need to load `SecuredComponent` because there I have custom layout and the `<router-outlet>` tag that will display this route's children.

But `'/secured'` isn't a valid route for users to land, because `SecuredComponent` is just a placeholder, so I need to automatically redirect them to `'application'` child route.

The problem is that the defined redirect function gets only called when I enter to a non-existing route, like for example `'secured/any-fake-route'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'application' }` definition was at the very bottom, so it nevers gets called when user visited `'/secured'` because `''` was a valid route and was matched first.

I fixed this as follows:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'application' },
    { path: '', component: SecuredComponent, canActivate: [SecuredMiddlewareService], children: [
        { path: 'application', loadChildren: 'app/application/application.module#ApplicationModule'}
    ]},
    { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'application' },
];
```

Pay attention to the first line. When users visits `'/secured'` then they are automatically redirected to `'/secured/application'`. Because of `'application'` is a child route of `''`, then they both gets called.

So, with this configuration, all of the followings examples redirects successfully to `'/secured/application'` as desired:

- `'/secured'`
- `'/secured/application'`
- `'/secured/any-fake-route'`